# Random Class with seed

Tags: java, random

```
    long seed = 0;
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    int rand100 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        rand100 = rand.nextInt();
    System.out.println(rand100);
```

I wrote this code to get 100th random integer value of given seed. I want to know if there is a way to get 100th random integer value of given seed without calling `nextInt()` 100 times.

Comment: What do you mean by *"without using every single random integer in front of it"*?

Comment: I used rand.nextInt() methods hundred time to get I want. I want to know if I can access it with more effecient way.

Comment: I don't get your question. It looks like you have already found out how to seed a `Random` instance. So your `Random` will always return the same sequence of numbers when fed with this seed. Can you demonstrate the problem or explain it in more detail?

Comment: You mean something like `List<Integer> values = rand.giveMe100Ints();`? You can use the `Stream` methods.

Comment: Likewise, `Integer value = rand.getNthRandomInt(100)`  does not exist either.   nextInt() is fast anyway, so don't worry about it unless you find performance really is a problem for some reason.   By the way, you're probably not improving anything by looping the hundred time - it won't make the resulting numbers any more "random".

Comment: What is it exactly you are asking? If you do not want your value to be randomize, then don't use random. Isn't it just assign what ever number you want `int num = xxx` ?

Comment: As mentioned in the java.util.Random javadocs, the Random class generates pseudo random numbers using a linear congruential algorithm.  Since this algorithm updates the internal state with each calculated number, to get the nth random number you need to calculate all the previous ones to get to that state.  That is a common characteristic with computer generated random number algorithms.

Comment: This is usually called *jumping*, but not all PRNGs support that (and even less implement it). So often one could achieve O(logn) instead of O(n) to get the n-th number. (that being said: make sure that's really what you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way to get `100`-th random integer value of given seed **without** calling `nextInt()` `100` times.

**No**, there is no way to directly get the `100`-th random number of the sequence without first generating the other `99` values. That's simply because of how the generation works in Java, the values depend on their previous values.

If you want to go into details, take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java#Random). The internal seed changes with every call of the `next` method, using the previous seed:

```
nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
```

So in order to get the seed for the `100`-th value, you need to know the seed for the `99`-th value, which needs the seed for the `98`-th value and so on.

---

However, you can easily get the `100`-th value with a more compact statement like

```
long seed = ...
int amount = 100;

Random rnd = new Random(seed);

// Generate sequence of 100 random values, discard 99 and get the last
int val = rnd.ints(100).skip(amount - 1).findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Keep in mind that this still computes all previous values, as explained. It just discards them.

---

After you have computed that value for the first time, you could just hardcode it into your program. Let's suppose you have tested it and it yields `123`. Then, if the seed does not change, the value will always be `123`. So you could just do

```
int val = 123;
```

The sequences remain the same through multiple instance of the JVM, so the value will always be valid for this seed. Don't know about release cycles though, I think it's allowed for `Random` to change its behavior through different versions of Java.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As long as the `seed` is constant, then the result of executing this 100 times will yield the same result **every** time. As such, you can just do

```
int rand100 = -1331702554;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code you gave. Is it along the line of the [xkcd random number comic](https://xkcd.com/221/)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sort of. OP's code uses the Java prng with a fixed seed of `0` and then iterates 100 times to find the 101st int. That's a constant. Because of the way the prng works. The 101st value will ***always*** be as posted (at least with my version of the JRE, other versions *could* have different results).

Comment: I'm not sure that's what OP asked for. After reading the question again, I think he asks for how to get the `100`-th value of the sequence directly, without first generating the other `99` values. Let's wait for OP to clarify this.

Comment: @Zabuza I know that is what OP is asking. My answer is yes, but only if you know the seed. Because then you can precompute the 100-th value. As I have here. Notice I do not generate any values here. Now, if the seed isn't known before hand, then the answer is just **no** (afaik).

Comment: Then I must admit that I don't get your answer. The `next` method generates values based on seeds and the seeds change with every generation, they depend on the previous seed. So in order to get the `100`-th value you need to simulate the generation up to that point, effectively computing and then discarding all other `99` values, don't you?

Comment: @Zabuza **Once**. Not every time. Run OP's code. It will set `rand100` to `-1331702554`. That's all. But it will do it every time. If we know the seed before hand, then we can hardcode the solution to finding the 100th value. I think we're saying the same thing really, notice the question wasn't how do I replicate the internal state of the random generator so that I can generate sequences of values.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct, you search for some seeded method like

```
int[] giveMeInts(int amount, long seed);
```

There exists something very similar, the `Stream` methods of `Random` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)):

```
long seed  = ...
int amount = 100;

Random rnd = new Random(seed);

IntStream values = rnd.ints(amount);
```

You could collect the stream values in collections like `List<Integer>` or an `int[]` array:

```
List<Integer> values = rnd.ints(amount).collect(Collectors.toList());

int[] values = rnd.ints(amount).toArray();
```

The methods will use the **seed** of the `Random` object, so if fed with the same seed they will always produce the same sequence of values.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I think OP is asking how to get 100th random number, not how to get 100 random numbers.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Possible, let's wait for OP to clarify this.